# Custom configuring Bottom Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

Is it possible to create bottom nav in react native such that number of screen it holds is 5 and number of (icon+text) in bottom nav is 4?

Comment: Yes, you have to create custom tab navigator.

Comment: do you want your react native app contains 5 bottom navigation screen?

Comment: @UA_ yes but bottom nav bar should have only 4 nav icons